# Current way of creating Google Maps custom info windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

There is a two-year old post on this topic here: [Creating custom info windows in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579777/creating-custom-info-windows-in-google-maps).

I wonder whether after two years this is still the best solution or there are other, possibly simpler way of creating custom info winodws.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried the two-year-old InfoBox, but the [best custom solution I've seen for V3 is also called InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/). It has a lot of options, so it is not simpler than the old InfoBox. This can be both annoying for casual use but powerful when you need a specific look.

[Here's a page I wrote using InfoBox](https://files.nyu.edu/hc742/public/googlemaps/mylatlng.html) where you can mark LatLngs by clicking.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want something like the following:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {});
var infoWin = google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: 'Window Content' });

infoWin.open(map);
```

See the following for more details:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

Comment: This is nice, because is standard of Google Maps. However it does not allow to style the window itself. Or does it?

Comment: You can write whatever HTML you want to the window and style it that way. Can also specify a few options like `pixelOffset` and qzIndex` to help with styling. Take a look at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions