# Implementing a custom info window on googlemaps?

Tags: php, google-maps, customization, infowindow

I need to implement a custom info window on my google map.

I found this custom info window here : [Creating custom info windows in Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2579777/creating-custom-info-windows-in-google-maps)

I used the code provided by Googles Developers page , to create the map and everything worked great with the typical info window. Now i changed my code to try and implement the above custom info window , called "infobox" . However it is not working. I am not sure if i used the code correctly.

This is my code for the google map. Note the infoBox function , is the custom info window.

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL and Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
        shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });

      //var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
      infobox = new InfoBox({ width: "260px" }); // initialize

      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("testing.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infobox, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infobox, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        //infoWindow.setContent(html);
        //infoWindow.open(map, marker);
        infobox.setContent(html);  // set content
        infobox.open(map, marker);   // open on the marker
        infobox.draw(); // to redraw if infobox size changed
        //infobox.close();



      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }


    function InfoBox(opt_opts) {
        opt_opts = opt_opts || {};
        this.imgPath='img/infoBox/';
        google.maps.OverlayView.apply(this, arguments);
        // Standard options (in common with google.maps.InfoWindow):
        this.content_ = opt_opts.content || "";
        this.maxWidth_ = opt_opts.maxWidth || 0;
        this.pixelOffset_ = opt_opts.pixelOffset || new google.maps.Size(0, 0);
        this.position_ = opt_opts.position || new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0);
        this.zIndex_ = opt_opts.zIndex || null;

        // Additional options (unique to InfoBox):
        this.boxStyle_ = opt_opts || {};
        this.infoBoxClearance_ = new google.maps.Size(1, 1);
        this.isHidden_ = opt_opts.isHidden || false;
        this.pane_ = "overlayMouseTarget";
        this.enableEventPropagation_ = opt_opts.enableEventPropagation || false;
        this.div_ = null;
        this.closeListener_ = null;
        this.eventListener1_ = null;
        this.eventListener2_ = null;
        this.eventListener3_ = null;
        this.contextListener_ = null;
        this.fixedWidthSet_ = null;
    }

    /* InfoBox extends OverlayView in the Google Maps API v3. */
    InfoBox.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

    // Creates the DIV representing the InfoBox. @private
    InfoBox.prototype.createInfoBoxDiv_ = function(){
        var bw, me = this;

        // This handler prevents an event in the InfoBox from being passed on to the map.
        var cancelHandler = function (e){ e.cancelBubble = true; if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); };
        // This handler ignores the current event in the InfoBox and conditionally prevents the event from being passed on to the map. It is used for the contextmenu event.
        var ignoreHandler = function (e) { e.returnValue = false; if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault(); if (!me.enableEventPropagation_){ e.cancelBubble = true; if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation(); } };

        if (!this.div_){    // first time create
            this.div_ = document.createElement("div");
            this.div_.className = 'infowindow';
            this.setBoxStyle_();

            // Apply required styles:
            if (this.zIndex_ !== null) this.div_.style.zIndex = this.zIndex_;

            this.div_.contentDiv = document.createElement('div');
            this.div_.contentDiv.className = 'infowindow-wrapper';
            this.div_.contentDiv.innerHTML = this.content_;
            this.div_.innerHTML = '<img src="'+this.imgPath+'close.png" align="right" class="infowindow-close">';
            this.div_.appendChild(this.div_.contentDiv);

            // Add the InfoBox DIV to the DOM
            this.getPanes()[this.pane_].appendChild(this.div_);
            this.addClickHandler_();
            if (this.div_.style.width) this.fixedWidthSet_ = true;
            else {
                if (this.maxWidth_ !== 0 && this.div_.offsetWidth > this.maxWidth_) {
                    this.div_.style.width = this.maxWidth_;
                    this.fixedWidthSet_ = true;
                } 
                else { // The following code is needed to overcome problems with MSIE
                    bw = this.getBoxWidths_();
                    this.div_.style.width = (this.div_.offsetWidth - bw.left - bw.right) + "px";
                    this.fixedWidthSet_ = false;
                }
            }

            //add shadow
            this.shadowContainer_ = document.createElement("div");
            this.shadowContainer_.style.position='absolute';
            this.shadowContainer_.style.display = 'block';
            this.shadowContainer_.style.zIndex='-99';
            this.getPanes()['overlayShadow'].appendChild(this.shadowContainer_);

            this.shadow = document.createElement('img');
            this.shadow.src = this.imgPath+'shadow.png';
            this.shadow.style.position='absolute';
            this.shadow.style.width = '100%';
            this.shadow.style.height    = '100%';

            this.shadowContainer_.appendChild(this.shadow);
            if (!this.enableEventPropagation_) {
                this.eventListener1_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_.contentDiv, "mousedown", cancelHandler);
                this.eventListener2_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "click", function(e){
                    e.cancelBubble = true; if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
                    if (GoogleMap && GoogleMap.closeEditors) GoogleMap.closeEditors(true);              
                });
                //this.eventListener3_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "dblclick", cancelHandler);
                try{ this.eventListener3_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "dblclick", facilityEditor);}catch(e){}
            }
            this.contextListener_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "contextmenu", ignoreHandler);

            var contentWidth = parseInt(this.div_.style.width.slice(0,-2)), contentHeight = this.div_.offsetHeight;
            this.wrapperParts = { //create an object to reference each image
                tl:{l:-26, t:-26, w:26, h:26},
                t:{l:0, t:-26, w:contentWidth, h:26},
                tr:{l:contentWidth, t:-26, w:26, h:26},
                l:{l:-26, t:0, w:26, h:contentHeight},
                r:{l:contentWidth, t:0, w:26, h: contentHeight },
                bl:{l:-26, t:contentHeight, w:26, h:26},
                b:{l:0, t:contentHeight, w:contentWidth, h:26},
                br:{l:contentWidth, t:contentHeight, w:26, h:26},
                p:{l:contentWidth-170, t:contentHeight+18, w:92, h:77 }
            }
            for (i in this.wrapperParts){ //create the image DOM objects
                var img = document.createElement('img');
                img.src = this.imgPath + i + '.png'; //load the image from your local image directory based on the property name of the wrapperParts object
                img.style.position='absolute'; //set the appropriate positioning attributes
                img.style.top=this.wrapperParts[i].t+'px';
                img.style.left=this.wrapperParts[i].l+'px';
                img.style.width=this.wrapperParts[i].w+'px';
                img.style.height=this.wrapperParts[i].h+'px';
                this.div_.appendChild(img);
                this.wrapperParts[i].img = img;
            }
            google.maps.event.trigger(this, "domready");
        }

        else {
            var contentWidth = parseInt(this.div_.style.width.slice(0,-2)), contentHeight = this.div_.offsetHeight, twp=this.wrapperParts;
            twp.t.img.style.width=contentWidth+'px';
            twp.tr.img.style.left=contentWidth+'px';
            twp.l.img.style.height=contentHeight+'px';
            twp.r.img.style.left=contentWidth+'px';
            twp.r.img.style.height=contentHeight+'px';
            twp.bl.img.style.top=contentHeight+'px';
            twp.b.img.style.top=contentHeight+'px';
            twp.b.img.style.width=contentWidth+'px';
            twp.br.img.style.left=contentWidth+'px';
            twp.br.img.style.top=contentHeight+'px';
            twp.p.img.style.left=(contentWidth-170)+'px';
            twp.p.img.style.top=(contentHeight+18)+'px';
        }
    };

    InfoBox.prototype.addClickHandler_=function(){ 
        this.closeListener_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_.firstChild, 'click', this.getCloseClickHandler_());
        try{ this.eventListener3_ = google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.div_, "dblclick", facilityEditor);}catch(e){}
    };
    InfoBox.prototype.getCloseClickHandler_=function () { var me = this; return function(){ me.close(); google.maps.event.trigger(me, "closeclick"); }; };

    //Pans the map so that the InfoBox appears entirely within the map's visible area. @private
    InfoBox.prototype.panBox_ = function (disablePan) {
      if (!disablePan) {
        var map = this.getMap();
        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        // The degrees per pixel
        var mapDiv = map.getDiv();
        var mapWidth = mapDiv.offsetWidth;
        var mapHeight = mapDiv.offsetHeight;
        var boundsSpan = bounds.toSpan();
        var longSpan = boundsSpan.lng();
        var latSpan = boundsSpan.lat();
        var degPixelX = longSpan / mapWidth;
        var degPixelY = latSpan / mapHeight;

        // The bounds of the map
        var mapWestLng = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();
        var mapEastLng = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
        var mapNorthLat = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
        var mapSouthLat = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();

        // The bounds of the box
        var position = this.position_;
        var iwOffsetX = this.pixelOffset_.width;
        var iwOffsetY = this.pixelOffset_.height;
        var padX = this.infoBoxClearance_.width;
        var padY = this.infoBoxClearance_.height;

        var iwWestLng = position.lng() + (iwOffsetX - padX - this.div_.contentDiv.offsetWidth/2 - 450) * degPixelX; // 450 - move right - from under the sidebar
        var iwEastLng = position.lng() + (iwOffsetX + padX + 220) * degPixelX;
        var iwNorthLat = position.lat() - (iwOffsetY - padY - this.div_.contentDiv.offsetHeight - 180) * degPixelY; // 180 - move down - from under the top search bar
        var iwSouthLat = position.lat() - (iwOffsetY + padY + 20) * degPixelY;

        // Calculate center shift
        var shiftLng = (iwWestLng < mapWestLng ? mapWestLng - iwWestLng : 0) + (iwEastLng > mapEastLng ? mapEastLng - iwEastLng : 0);
        var shiftLat = (iwNorthLat > mapNorthLat ? mapNorthLat - iwNorthLat : 0) + (iwSouthLat < mapSouthLat ? mapSouthLat - iwSouthLat : 0);
        if (!(shiftLat === 0 && shiftLng === 0)) {
          // Move the map to the new shifted center.
          var c = map.getCenter();
          map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(c.lat() - shiftLat, c.lng() - shiftLng));
        }
      }
    };

    // Sets the style of the InfoBox. @private
     InfoBox.prototype.setBoxStyle_ = function () {
      var i;
      var boxStyle = this.boxStyle_;
      for (i in boxStyle)  if (boxStyle.hasOwnProperty(i))  this.div_.style[i] = boxStyle[i];
      // Fix up opacity style for benefit of MSIE:
      if (typeof this.div_.style.opacity !== "undefined")  this.div_.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + (this.div_.style.opacity * 100) + ")";
    };

    // Get the widths of the borders of the InfoBox. @private; @return {Object} widths object (top, bottom left, right)
    InfoBox.prototype.getBoxWidths_ = function () {
      var computedStyle;
      var bw = {top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0};
      var box = this.div_;
      if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle) {
        computedStyle = box.ownerDocument.defaultView.getComputedStyle(box, "");
        if (computedStyle) {
          // The computed styles are always in pixel units (good!)
          bw.top = parseInt(computedStyle.borderTopWidth, 10) || 0;
          bw.bottom = parseInt(computedStyle.borderBottomWidth, 10) || 0;
          bw.left = parseInt(computedStyle.borderLeftWidth, 10) || 0;
          bw.right = parseInt(computedStyle.borderRightWidth, 10) || 0;
        }
      } 
      else if (document.documentElement.currentStyle) { // MSIE
        if (box.currentStyle) {
          // The current styles may not be in pixel units, but assume they are (bad!)
          bw.top = parseInt(box.currentStyle.borderTopWidth, 10) || 0;
          bw.bottom = parseInt(box.currentStyle.borderBottomWidth, 10) || 0;
          bw.left = parseInt(box.currentStyle.borderLeftWidth, 10) || 0;
          bw.right = parseInt(box.currentStyle.borderRightWidth, 10) || 0;
        }
      }
      return bw;
    };

    // Invoked when <tt>close</tt> is called. Do not call it directly.
    InfoBox.prototype.onRemove = function () {
      if (this.div_) {
         this.shadowContainer_.parentNode.removeChild(this.shadowContainer_);
        this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
        this.div_ = null;
      }
    };

    //Draws the InfoBox based on the current map projection and zoom level.
    InfoBox.prototype.draw = function(){
        this.createInfoBoxDiv_();
        var pixPosition = this.getProjection().fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.position_);

        this.div_.style.left = (pixPosition.x - this.div_.offsetWidth + 180 ) + "px";
        this.div_.style.top = (pixPosition.y - this.div_.offsetHeight - 125) + "px";

        this.shadowContainer_.style.left = (pixPosition.x - this.div_.offsetWidth + 220 ) + 'px';
        this.shadowContainer_.style.top = (pixPosition.y - this.div_.offsetHeight - 130) + "px";

        this.shadowContainer_.style.height = (this.div_.offsetHeight+100 ) + 'px';
        this.shadowContainer_.style.width = (this.div_.offsetWidth+100 ) + 'px';

        if (this.isHidden_) this.div_.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        else this.div_.style.visibility = "visible";

        this.panBox_();
    };


    InfoBox.prototype.setContent = function(content){
        this.content_ = content;
        if (this.div_){// Odd code required to make things work with MSIE.
            this.div_.style.visibility='hidden'
            if (!this.fixedWidthSet_) this.div_.style.width = "";
            this.div_.contentDiv.innerHTML = content;
            // Perverse code required to make things work with MSIE. (Ensures the close box does, in fact, float to the right.)
            if (!this.fixedWidthSet_){ this.div_.style.width = this.div_.offsetWidth + "px"; this.div_.contentDiv.innerHTML = content; }
            this.addClickHandler_();
        }
        // This event is fired when the content of the InfoBox changes. @name InfoBox#content_changed; @event
        google.maps.event.trigger(this, "content_changed");
    };

    //Sets the geographic location of the InfoBox. @param {LatLng} latlng
    InfoBox.prototype.setPosition = function (latlng) { 
      this.position_ = latlng;
      if (this.div_) this.draw();
      //This event is fired when the position of the InfoBox changes. @name InfoBox#position_changed;  @event
      google.maps.event.trigger(this, "position_changed");
    };


    InfoBox.prototype.getContent = function () {  return this.content_; }; //Returns the content of the InfoBox. @returns {string}
    InfoBox.prototype.show = function (){ this.isHidden_ = false; this.div_.style.visibility = "visible"; }; //Shows the InfoBox.
    InfoBox.prototype.hide = function (){ this.isHidden_ = true; this.div_.style.visibility = "hidden"; }; //Hides the InfoBox.

    InfoBox.prototype.open = function (map, anchor) {
        if (anchor) this.position_ = anchor.getPosition();
        this.setMap(map);
    };

    //Removes the InfoBox from the map.
    InfoBox.prototype.close = function (){
      if (this.closeListener_) {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(this.closeListener_);
        this.closeListener_ = null;
      }
      if (this.contextListener_) {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(this.contextListener_);
        this.contextListener_ = null;
      }

      this.setMap(null);
    };


    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 600px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

In the above code , i just changed everything mentioning infowindow , with the new infobox , and added the new function InfoBox(). However i am not sure , how and where i should use the

```
infobox.setContent(html);  // set content
infobox.open(map, marker);   // open on the marker
infobox.draw(); // to redraw if infobox size changed
infobox.close();
```

Where should i use the infobox.close() function? In my code i commented this line , cause i didnt know how to use it.

Comment: @tborychowski , can you plz take a look at this. I got the code , from an answer u gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your missing a `position: absolute` style for the infobox and also background color if it's not set in the css (originally I had that set in css, that's why it worked for me :-))

look for this line in your code:

```
this.div_.className = 'infowindow';
```

and add this below:

```
this.div_.style.position = 'absolute';
this.div_.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
```

You should also add some images for the infobox as the whole box is build based on the images (you'll find references in the script).